# Долгая загрузка в Unity 2020

Tags: unity3d, 2d, unity3d-editor

При обновлении скрипта (очень простого) происходит вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Время в промежутке от 40 до 110с (но было и больше).

На пк стоит gtx 1050 Ti 4gb, i5 9th.

Вот скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 15f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 50f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float jumpAxis = Input.GetAxis("Jump");

        Vector2 move = new Vector2(moveX, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;
        Vector2 jump = Vector2.up * jumpAxis * jumpSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        Debug.Log(move);
        Debug.Log(jump);

        //transform.position += move;
        rb.AddForce(jump + move, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Должно ли так долго загружаться? Или у меня в коде грубая ошибка?

P.S. после загрузки нажимаю Играть, происходит такая же загрузка (повторно).

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить Unity

Comment: Ну как, проблему решили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Часто это из-за антифируса. У вас случайно не стоит Avast? Если да, внесите Unity в список доверенных приложений.
- Хорошо бы проект и Юнити положить на SSD.
- В меню Assets может помочь нажатие кнопки "Reimport All".
- Если в проекте много различных скриптов, то рекомендую почитать про [Assembly](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html).

Comment: я с 2020 перешел на 2018, а там все норм. Антивируса у меня воще нет)) Только malwerbytes. Но я вам защитаю как правильный ответ) Может другим это поможет

Comment: @Данил лучше, всё же, разобраться, в чём проблема. Или хотя бы попробовать 2019, т.к. 2018 уже не LTS вроде.

Comment: 2020 все же только появилась, баги и тд. 2019, Ну хз я проект уже начал на 2018